# .NET MAUI Project Build Failure After Updating to .NET 8

Tags: c#, maui

Following the upgrade guidelines provided in the .NET MAUI documentation and utilizing the 'Upgrade Assistant' tool as recommended in the .NET blog, I updated my project from .NET 7 to .NET 8. However, I'm encountering build issues with the following error:

```
NETSDK1005 Assets file '[path]\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. WhatsYum [path]Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
```

Even after updating the csproj file to target `net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0`, deleting and rebuilding the `bin/obj` directories, and performing a NuGet package restore, the problem persists.

Furthermore, investigating the `obj/project.assets.json` file revealed an uninformative error: `"code": "NU1105" Unable to read project information for '[project name]': Sequence contains more than one element`.

I've attempted to start from scratch by deleting the directory and pulling the project again from Git. Incrementally updating components did not resolve the issue either. I'm uncertain about what else to try or investigate to resolve this build failure.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this build issue after the upgrade to .NET 8 in a .NET MAUI project would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you go looking for other folks who have had that error (perhaps not .NET 8 related). Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695504/error-nu1105-unable-to-find-project-information-the-project-file-may-be-invali

Comment: Yes, have tried all the answers there. The other projects have upgraded fine to .net 8, just the MAUI one is failing

Comment: I'm getting the same issues :-(

Comment: fixed it by reading the stackoverflow post suggested by Flydog57 (solution restore fixed it for me)